# Shift Thread Start / for loop doubled?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to not start all of my threads at the same time, so the first time i loop through my for-loop, i want them to sleep. Weirdly, they go through (i == 0) twice. What do I not see?
Thanks for your advice! This is the output:

- i: 0, iD: 0, CurrentTime: 1612092185653
- i: 0, iD: 0, CurrentTime: 1612092185664
- i: 0, iD: 1, CurrentTime: 1612092185709
- i: 0, iD: 1, CurrentTime: 1612092185718
- i: 0, iD: 2, CurrentTime: 1612092185756
- i: 0, iD: 2, CurrentTime: 1612092185765
- i: 0, iD: 3, CurrentTime: 1612092185811
- i: 0, iD: 3, CurrentTime: 1612092185823
- i: 0, iD: 4, CurrentTime: 1612092185863
- i: 0, iD: 4, CurrentTime: 1612092185870

```
public static Result compute(ServiceBot bot) throws InterruptedException {

       for (int i = 0; i < orderList.size(); i++) {

           System.out.println("Was ist mit i? :" + i);
           
           if (i == 0) {

               int iD = bot.getID();

               switch (iD) {
               case 0:
                   System.out.println("i: " + i + ", iD: " + iD + ", CurrentTime: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                   break;
               case 1:
                   Thread.sleep(50);
                   System.out.println("i: " + i + ", iD: " + iD + ", CurrentTime: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                   break;
               case 2:
                   Thread.sleep(100);
                   System.out.println("i: " + i + ", iD: " + iD + ", CurrentTime: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                   break;
               case 3:
                   Thread.sleep(150);
                   System.out.println("i: " + i + ", iD: " + iD + ", CurrentTime: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                   break;
               case 4:
                   Thread.sleep(200);
                   System.out.println("i: " + i + ", iD: " + iD + ", CurrentTime: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                   break;
               }

           }

           boolean dummyBool = orderList.get(i).getUnhandled();

           if (dummyBool = true) {
               bot.doStuff();
               Thread.sleep(sleep);

           } else {
           bot.doNothing();
           }

       }

       int wait = 50;

       return new Result(wait);
   }
```

Comment: That's race condition. Taking i as atomicInteger should solve the problem https://www.journaldev.com/1095/atomicinteger-java

Comment: That output doesn't appear to be the output from the code. Where is the "Was ist mit..." part? Also can you make a complete compilable example?

Comment: I think you're calling compute either with the same bot 2x's or you're creating bots with the same ID.

Comment: argh i created the bot list twice for some reason, thanks @matt !